# Vertically center responsive iframe

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design

I'm using the technique [described here](http://blog.embed.ly/post/64309421761/easy-responsive-embeds) to make an iframe (video) responsive. Essentially the iframe is absolutely positioned within a wrapper element with a 100% width. The wrapper element has it's padding set based on the aspect ratio of the video:

```
.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    /* video height / video width */
    padding-bottom: 56.2%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.embed-responsive iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I need to be able to center the iframe vertically in the parent container (which has a 100% height).

I've achieved this before using [this technique](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) but it only works on `inline-block` elements. If I change `.embed-responsive` to `inline-block` it breaks.

So is there an alternative (**preferably CSS only**) technique I can use to vertically center the iframe, whilst still being responsive? This must work as the browser is resized.

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/xfA3L/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I figured this out after 2 minutes of posting :)

Making `.embed-resposive` absolutely positioned with `top:50%` and margin top set to half the height ratio `(video height / video width) / 2` I can center it vertically:

```
.embed-responsive {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    /* video height / video width */
    padding-bottom: 56.2%;
    /* the above value * 0.5 */
    margin-top: -28.1%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle has been updated.

Comment: you should have mentioned the enclosing container div with height: 100%, as demonstrated in your question's fiddle example, I found it crucial to get it to work.

Comment: This makes my video as large as the entire window, and puts empty space below it :(