# How to center my iFrame video (HTML, CSS)

Tags: css, html

I am new to HTML and CSS coding and I got a challenge right now.
I am currently looking for the solution on how I can center my iFrame video in the center of the page.

**HTML**

```
<section id="video">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="video-container">
      <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rXuWb0RXfEI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.video-container {
   position:relative;
   padding-bottom:56.25%;
   padding-top:30px;
   margin-top: 100px;
   height:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
     position: absolute;
     width:80%;
     height:80%;
}

.row {
     text-align: center;
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: this may help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366957/how-to-center-an-iframe-horizontally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically center responsive iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645291/vertically-center-responsive-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually just leave out the lower part of your css and just use the following:

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. The problem is that I only see 1/8 of the video if I use this CSS.

Comment: Oh right, you also have to set the iframe width correctly like this: `<iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rXuWb0RXfEI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

Just try to change this :

```
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I only get 1/4 of my video that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

<div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wmgWITMWcmE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: We're almost there... I want this not 100% width, but 80%. If I use 80%, the video will end up on the left side of the page instead of in the center.